# wrapper for http with http.Handler

Tags: go

How to build a wrapper for types `http.Handler` and `http.HandlerFunc` ?

In the end of the chain (wrappers) the http server accepts `http.HandlerFunc` as type

- It's not possible to pass `http.Handler` to the server because routing is decided from parsing `r *http.Request` on each request

code

```
type Wrapper func(h http.Handler) http.Handler

func Wrap(h http.HandlerFunc, wrappers ...Wrapper) http.HandlerFunc {
    for _, wrapper := range wrappers {
        h = wrapper(h)
    }
    return h
}

func wrap_test(param1 string, param2 string) Wrapper {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
            // adding data to context here
            
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}
```

compile error

```
cannot use wrapper(h) (value of type http.Handler) as http.HandlerFunc value in assignment: need type assertion
```

This is what is passed to the http server. I can't really wrap my head around how to solve this differently?

```
Wrap(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Write([]byte("hello world"))
}, wrap_test("data1", "data2"))
```

## update

This is how I have designed the server part and why I have to pass `http.HandlerFunc` and not `http.Handler`

```
srv := &http.Server{
    Addr:               fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", h.host, h.port),
    Handler:            http.HandlerFunc(h.serve),
}

//  Route pattern handler
func (h *HTTP) serve(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var (
        match_route     *route
        allow           []string
    )
    
    ctx := r.Context()
    
    for _, route := range h.routes {
        if route.regex != nil {
            //  Regex path
            matches := route.regex.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
            len     := len(matches)
            if len > 0 {
                if route.method != ALL && r.Method != route.method {
                    allow = append(allow, route.method)
                    continue
                }
                
                //  Slug group capture
                if len > 1 {
                    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, CTX_HTTP, matches[1:])
                }
                
                match_route = route
                break
            }
        }else{
            //  Path
            if strings.HasPrefix(r.URL.Path, route.pattern) {
                if route.method != ALL && r.Method != route.method {
                    allow = append(allow, route.method)
                    continue
                }
                
                match_route = route
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    if match_route != nil {
        has_timeout := match_route.timeout > 0
        
        //  Apply timeout context
        if has_timeout {
            var cancel context.CancelFunc
            ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Duration(time.Duration(match_route.timeout) * time.Second))
            
            go func(){
                //  Serve HTTP request to client
                match_route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
                cancel()
            }()
            
            //  Wait until the context is done/canceled/timeout
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                //  Return HTTP 408 Timeout if request reached timeout
                if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
                    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusRequestTimeout), http.StatusRequestTimeout)
                }
            }
            return
        }
        
        //  Serve HTTP request to client
        match_route.handler(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
        return
    }
    
    //  Return HTTP 404/405 if no route was matched
    if len(allow) > 0 {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", strings.Join(allow, ", "))
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }else{
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
    }
}
```

Comment: http.HandlerFunc *is* a http.Handler implementation. If you make the argument to Wrap of type http.Handler you can pass a http.HandlerFunc just fine.

Comment: @Peter It's not possible to pass `http.Handler` to the server because routing is decided from parsing `r *http.Request` on each request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the compilation error by using a [method value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values) to get an http.HandlerFunc:

```
func Wrap(h http.HandlerFunc, wrappers ...Wrapper) http.HandlerFunc {
    for _, wrapper := range wrappers {
        h = wrapper(h).ServeHTTP // <-- method value expresion
    }
    return h
}
```

---

It is more conventional to follow the pattern in net/http package:  Write the core functions in terms of http.Handler.  Add `Func` [helpers](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#HandleFunc) for functions.

```
type Wrapper func(h http.Handler) http.Handler

func Wrap(h http.Handler, wrappers ...Wrapper) http.Handler {
    for _, wrapper := range wrappers {
        h = wrapper(h)
    }
    return h
}

func WrapFunc(h func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request), wrappers ...Wrapper) http.Handler {
    return Wrap(http.HandlerFunc(h), wrappers...)
}
```

Example use:

```
func wrap_test(param1 string, param2 string) Wrapper {
    return func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // adding data to context here

            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}

func main() {
    WrapFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("hello world"))
    }, wrap_test("data1", "data2"))

}
```

Comment: It's not possible to pass `http.Handler` to the server because routing is decided from parsing `r *http.Request` on each request

Comment: @clarkk See updated answer.  If you edit question to explain in more detail why http.Handler cannot be used, I may be able to help you with that as well.

Comment: have updated my question with more details about the server design